# Fabric: DAU vs Event users

Tags: android, google-fabric

I have Crashlycis / Fabric installed in my Android app.

Can someone explain me why DAU is much lower than particular event users?

Please take a look at DAU and 'Pro' event figures.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you see the same numbers in your web dashboard?

Comment: Hi. Yes. Exactly the same as in app.

Comment: It's worth to mention, that I'm logging this event just after Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier, like line below.

Comment: @ToddBurner any thoughts?